# Django - Save html data into a quillfield

Tags: django, quill

I have a model `Product` as below:

```
class Product(models.Model): 
    description = QuillField(null=True, blank=True)
```

In Django views how can I save html data in it ?

```
product = Product.objects.get(id=...) 
product.description = '<p> this is a test </p>'
product.save()
```

But I am getting an error: `can't parse value`

Comment: Share the full traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the content in a JSON blob, so:

```
import json

product = Product.objects.get(id=…)
product.description = json.dumps(
    {
        'delta': {'ops': []},
        'html': '<p> this is a test </p>',
    }
)
product.save()
```